# Customized color on progressbar delegate

Tags: c++, qt

Been trying to do this for quite a while and took advice from every forum post i could find but i still cant solve it. This is my current code and I would really like to change the color of the chunk on the progress bar. Every other setting is working, except the colors.

In my workspace object that fills up one subview on the MainWindow.

```
Workspace::Workspace( QWidget* parent) : QWidget( parent )
{
    QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();
    // ...
    tableView->setItemDelegate(new ProgressBarDelegate);
}
```

The delegate.cpp looks like this:

```
ProgressBarDelegate::ProgressBarDelegate( QObject* parent )
: QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void ProgressBarDelegate::paint( QPainter *painter,
                                 const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                 const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.column() == 2)
    {
        int progressPercentage = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();

        QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 progressBarOption;
        progressBarOption.rect = QRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y() + 5 , option.rect.width(), option.rect.height() / 1.5);
        progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
        progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
        progressBarOption.progress = progressPercentage;
        QPalette pal = progressBarOption.palette;
        QColor col = QColor(35, 35,25);
        pal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, col); // or QPalette::Window doesnt matter
        progressBarOption.palette = pal;

        if(option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        {
        }

        QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_ProgressBar,
                                            &progressBarOption,
                                            painter);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Currently, no matter what I do the color doesnt change from OSX standard light-gray.

Running OSX 10.6.7 and Qt 4.8.1 if that matters. thank you!

Edit:

I was able to do the following:

```
app.setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:horizontal { border: 2px solid green;background: cyan;height: 15px;margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;}");
```

But when I do this:

```
app.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar:horizontal { border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 3px; background: white; padding: 1px; }");
```

NOTHING changes on the progressbar. I am in theory not creating any progressbar objects, im just settings a style how I'm viewing my data in my delegate. But surely, I cant be the first person who would want to do this right?

Also, if this doesnt work, how can I do this (having a styled progressbar) in a tableview?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [Qt Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html), which allows us to customize UI of many controls to give unique look and feel across platforms. [Check this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar).

Create a new simple Qt Gui project, open UI Form editor and add a Progress Bar control from under 'Display Widgets' in tool window. Now write following code in constructor of `MainWindow`..

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Customize progress-bar's style..

    QString style = "QProgressBar {border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px; text-align: center;}";
    style += "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: #CD96CD; width: 10px; margin: 0.5px;}";

    // Assuming objectName is 'progressBar'..
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(style);
}
```

Compile and run.

If you just want to change that single `QProgressBar` control, then above method is sufficient, but if you want to apply styles at application level (say all `QProgressBar` controls and some other controls), then proper way is to create a `*.css` file, write styles using [Qt Style Sheet Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html) and then read that file in Qt and call

`QApplication::setStyleSheet(QString style)`.

Besides, style sheet uses the same syntax as CSS and also supports various selectors.

***Edit:***

I agree that above method works only with controls and not delegates. I found something for delegates also. Try following `paint` function.

```
void ProgressBarDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.column() == 2)
    {
        QProgressBar renderer;
        int progressPercentage = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();

        // Customize style using style-sheet..

        QString style = "QProgressBar { border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px; }";
        style += "QProgressBar::chunk { background-color: #05B8CC; width: 20px; }";

        renderer.resize(option.rect.size());
        renderer.setMinimum(0);
        renderer.setMaximum(100);
        renderer.setValue(progressPercentage);

        renderer.setStyleSheet(style);
        painter->save();
        painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
        renderer.render(painter);
        painter->restore();
    }
    else
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

So here the point is that instead of using `QStyleOption`, we can use directly the control itself as a renderer. Hope this helps..

Comment: how would i do this with a delegate? only progressbar code im using  is in one delegate for a tablevview

Comment: i really dont have a qprogressbar item or anything that i can set  i stylesheet on. this is driving me insane. why is it so hard to just change the color of something programatically?

Comment: @chikuba: Sorry I don't know much about delegates, but if you want to customize all progress-bars in your UI, then you can use `QApplication::setStyleSheet(style)` instead of `ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(style)` as I have mentioned in my answer. Style sheet  approach seemed to me much simpler to use.

Comment: yeah, read my edit of my post. my delegate doesnt act as a progessbar so the stylesheet doesnt aply to it for some reason

Comment: I'm not too sure why this answer gets a lot of upvotes since the style sheet doesnt work on styleItems.

Comment: that worked! also noticed that you have to set "progressBarOption.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Active;" in osx for the bars to not display as inactive

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, col);`

Use `pal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, col);`

This should `work`.

I used the code in Paintevent

```
   void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
   {
    QPainter painter(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(ShowPrintDialog()));
    QStyleOptionProgressBarV2 progressBarOption;
    progressBarOption.rect = QRect(20,20,30,30);
    progressBarOption.minimum = 0;
    progressBarOption.maximum = 100;
    progressBarOption.progress = 75;
    QPalette pal = progressBarOption.palette;
    QColor col = QColor(0,255,0);
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, col);
    progressBarOption.palette = pal;


    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ProgressBar,&progressBarOption, &painter);
    }
```

Comment: yeah it felt a bit wierd when the other stuff worked since they arent "set" methods

Comment: yeah the only difference is I put this code on the constructor of my dialog.

Comment: I just checked it in a dialog base App.

Comment: but my code is used as a delegate on a tableview and i never create a progressbar object

Comment: I did it with QStyleOptionProgressBarV2

Comment: cheers! i tried exactly that in my delegate but it doesnt work im affraid :( feels like  bug on osx since the bars look inactive (no colors are showing)